# Trying to scrape a specific element using Selenium but getting no results

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I cobbled together some code to login to a website and navigate to the specific pages I want to scrape from.  This part works fine.  Now, however, I'm searching for a specific element titled 'tspan' and I'm getting an error that reads:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'descendants'
```

If I go to the URL, right-click the element I want to grab, and click 'Inspect Element' I see the code behind the page, and it looks like this.

[image]

It looks like querying by 'g id' may work too.

[image]

So, I thought I could get all 'tspan' items, load all into a list, and write the list to a text file.  However, I'm getting no 'tspan' elements at all.  If I right-click the page and click 'View Page Source', I see no 'tspan' elements.  This is very weird!  The code behind the page is definitely different than what's rendered on the page itself.  Here's my code.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import webbrowser
import requests
from lxml import html
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
import time

# selenium
wd = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/Utility/geckodriver.exe", firefox_profile=profile)
url = "https://corp-internal.com/admin/?page=0"
wd.get(url)

# set username
time.sleep(2)
username = wd.find_element_by_id("identifierId")
username.send_keys("my_email@email.com")
wd.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()

# set password
time.sleep(2)
password = wd.find_element_by_name("password")
password.send_keys("my_pswd")
wd.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").click()

all_text = []

# list of URLs
url_list = ['https://corp-internal.com/admin/graph?dag_id=emm1_daily_legacy',
'https://corp-internal.com/admin/graph?dag_id=eemm1_daily_legacy_history']
for link in url_list:
    #File = webbrowser.open(link)
    #File = requests.get(link)
    #data = File.text
    for link in bs.findAll('tspan'):
        alldata = all_text.append(link.get('tspan'))

outF = open('C:/Users/ryans/OneDrive/Desktop/test.txt', 'w')
outF.writelines(alldata)
outF.close()
```

Comment: So what is your problem? How code before `all_text = []` related to code after it? On which line did you get `AttributeError`? What your `for` loops suppose to do?

Comment: all_text = [] is always empty.  My understanding is that you create an empty list to hole the data you want to load (all_text), loop through all URLs and load all data points into this list (all_text), and you're done.  Is that right?  The error occurs on this line:  alldata = all_text.append(link.get('tspan')).  When I hit that line I get this: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'descendants'

Comment: I think you have posted some other code @ryguy72 . please share the `stacktrace` too. I am a little surprised because you are using all three `beautifulSoup`, `lxml` and `webdriver`.

Comment: I feel like the program is NOT navigating to the first URL in the loop.  I'm going to the parent URL, logging in, and then trying to loop through child URLs.  I feel like the login is fine, but I'm not getting to that first URL in url_list.  How can I set the focus to that url_list variable?

Comment: Your error probably is on line `for link in bs.findall('tspan'):`, here are my thoughts. 1. You are using Beautifulsoup incorrectly, please read its [Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup). You need to go the url using selenium driver and then make soup using html source of page. 2. May be you don't need to use BeautifulSoup, selenium can find the `tspan` elements in the page for you and then you can text attribute from them.